# Links loaded in from Ajax posted page not working with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a search form on my main page (dashboard.php) that posts to a page (load-request.php) that then creates links that look like this which are loaded into a div under the search form using $('#results-div').html(data) in my JS:

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="load-request-btn">Joe Schmoe</a>
```

I also have the exact same link hard coded under that div that I used for testing.

When I click on one of these links, it should load another page into another div.

So here's the problem. Nothing happens when clicking the dynamically generated links UNTIL AFTER I click on the hard coded link (which has always worked), then the dynamic links work.

Also, I noticed that whenever you do a new search, the links load the same number of times as the number of searches. In other words, if you do three searches, the links "blink" twice before remaining.

Here's my code:

In the Header of dashboard.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function load_ajax_search(formURL,postData,status) {
  $.ajax({
  url: formURL,
  type: "POST",
  data: postData,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false
  },
  success: function(data) {
    //alert("AJAX: "+data);//This shows the correct html links
    var f_data = data;
    if (!$.trim(data)){ 
        $(status).html(data);
    } else {
        $(status).html(data);
    }
  },
  error: function(errorThrown) {
    $(status).text("Username or Password not found!");
  }
});
}

//THIS LOADS THE PAGE INTO A DIV AFTER THE LINK IS CLICKED
$('.load-request-btn').click(function() {
   var requestID=$(this).attr('id');
    var requestURL="load-request.php?requestID="+requestID;
   $( "#load-div" ).load(requestURL, function() {
    });
});

 //THIS POSTS THE FORM DATA TO LOAD_AJAX_SEARCH()
   $('#btn-request-search').on('click',function(){
        //alert("CLICKED");
    $('#request-search-results').load('load-rsearch-results.php');
    var form_id = '#'+$(this).closest('form').attr('id');
    var formURL = $(form_id).attr('action');
    var postData = new FormData($(form_id)[0]);
    var status = "#request-search-results";
    load_ajax_search(formURL,postData,status);
   });
  });
```

Any help is always greatly appreciated.

The search form:

```
<form id="search-requests" method="post" action="load-rsearch-results.php">
 <div class="md-form">
  <label for="search-by" class="request-label">Part Number</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="search-by" name="search-by">
  <option value="First">First Name</option>
  <option value="Last">Last Name</option>
  <option value="Company">Company</option>
  <option value="Email">Email</option>
</select>
</div>
 <div class="md-form">
  <label for="search" class="request-label"></label>
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control">
</div>
<p><a class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-request-search">Submit Request</a></p>
```

load-search-results.php

```
<?php
$selected=$_POST['search-by'];
$search=$_POST['search'];
include '../connect.php';
$sql="SELECT * FROM hc_requests WHERE ".$selected."='".$search."'";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
$date='';
While ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
$date=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($row['DateEntered']));
    print '<a href="#" id="'.$row['ID'].'" class="load-request-btn">'.$date.' / '.$row['Last'].', '.$row['First'].'</a><br>';
}
if ($date=='') {
    print "NOT FOUND";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi as these links are dynamically created you need to bind it with static elements . i.e : `$(document).on("click",".load-request-btn",function(){ //your code});`

Comment: Thank you, Swati! That fixed the link issue. Although, I'm still having the issue of multiple loading of the links with each search. I'm assuming I have to unset some variables?

Comment: Sorry please can you elaborate more ? what do you mean by `multiple loading of the links with each search...` ?

Comment: Neither `#results-div` nor `.btn-load-search` seem to be handled in the JS shown.  Where is the code which handles those clicks you describe? Increasing number of blinks suggests an increasing number of handlers firing, like you are attaching a new handler with each iteration.  Do your browser dev tools show 3 network requests firing?

Comment: SWATI - Each time you do a search, the function will cycles through an additional time causing the links to load each time. If I put an alert in the function, it will show up multiple times.

Comment: DON'T PANIC - #results-div is the id of the div that loads the request information after one of the links is clicked. That is working fine. In regards to .btn-load-search, I wrote the class of the links incorrectly. I've edited the link example above.

Comment: SWATI - I was wrong! It's not each time you do a search, it's each time you click on one of the links. If I do multiple searches without clicking on one of the generated links, it's fine. As soon as I click on one of the links, it seems to add one more cycle to the next search. Weird! I'm adding above my form and the php code that handles the data.

Comment: I was pointing out that the behaviour and problem you describe cannot be reproduced with the code you've shown us.  I still don't see `$('#results-div').html(data)` anywhere.  That suggests there is code you are not showing us.  If we can't see the code that actually causes the problem, we can only guess what is going on.

Comment: One thing - you have a typo in your `$.ajax()` - the closing `}` before your `success` callback should not be there.  Maybe a typo here on SO? If you remove that, it leaves the following 2 click handlers as part of the `load_ajax_search()` function.  If that is really true, it explains the problem - every time that function runs, you add 2 new click handlers.  Those don't replace previous click handlers, they are added.  Any clicks they handle will then be fired 2x, once for each handler. Next time `load_ajax_search()` fires, 2 new handlers will be added, so clicks will fire them 3x ...

Comment: First of all, thanks for all the help. I really do appreciate it. Secondly, my sincerest apologies. I'm embarrassed to say that I figured it out. I have all the JS in an include file and was including it at the top of every page that I was loading. Once I deleted all those includes, it started working properly.